# Find XmlElement in List<> using array of matching attribute names ... Using Linq

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I have an XmlElement with several attributes

```
xeObject = <Object Name="Object1" Site="Site1" ... />
```

I also have a list of XmlElements with several (possibly different) attributes

```
l_xeObject = <Object ... /><Object ... /> ... <Object ... />
```

I would like a function call like

```
FindMatchingElements(xeObject, l_xeObject, "Name", "Site")
```

where any elements in l_xeObject that have the same values as xeObject.Name and xeObject.Site are returned!

Can i do this with Linq?

... I already have the following function

```
public static List<XmlElement> GetXmlElementsFromListWithMatchingAttribute
    (XmlElement xeMatchOn, string sMatchingAttributeName, List<XmlElement> l_xeSearchIn)
{
    return (l_xeSearchIn
        .Where(xe => xe.Attributes[sMatchingAttributeName].Value
            == xeMatchOn.Attributes[sMatchingAttributeName].Value)
        ).ToList();
}
```

but it only uses one attribute.

Thanks to Frédéric for the answer i needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [All()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx) to match several attributes and [GetAttribute()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acwfyhc7.aspx) to avoid having to check for `null`:

```
public static IEnumerable<XmlElement> FindMatchingElements(XmlElement match,
    IEnumerable<XmlElement> elements, params string[] attributeNames)
{
    // Argument validation omitted for brevity.

    return elements.Where(
        element => attributeNames.All(
            name => element.GetAttribute(name) == match.GetAttribute(name)));
}
```

That said, if you really want to parse or generate XML markup with LINQ, consider using [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) instead of the DOM classes.

Comment: édéric, Thanks for your response. I had to change '.Attributes[name]' to '.Attributes[name].Value' to get it to work, but that means i now get an error if i specify an attribute in the params that is not present on the match element..?!

Comment: @user597118, you're absolutely right about `.Value` (I'm not used to `XmlElement` anymore, too much LINQ to XML I guess). I updated my answer to use [GetAttribute()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acwfyhc7.aspx) instead, which will return the empty string if the attribute is not present.

Comment: édéric, Awesome thanks! It is nice to be right about something, just don't tell my missus :-) I am just reading up on Linq to Xml and can already see the advantages... thanks for the link and necessary kick up the a**e!